# Duplicating HTML with jQuery when user prints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I need to take a webpage and, when the user either clicks file > print or [cmd + p], duplicate an article (HTML) and place the new article adjacent to the original article. The idea is to show a list online, and then print from the webpage a 2-up paper version that can be cut in half: 2 identical lists, one sheet of paper. I'm using print style sheets for the custom paper layout, and I'm using jquery to duplicate the HTML.

The part that I'm stuck on is how to duplicate right before the user sees the print dialog box. I don't want there to be two identical articles on the webpage by default. I'd also want to remove the duplicate article after printing is done, but that's maybe not as important.

```
<script>
/*  instead of window.onclick, is there an "on print" function? */
    window.onclick = function() {
        var $newArticle = $('article').clone();
        $($newArticle).css({'margin-left':'1.3cm'});
        $($newArticle).insertAfter("article");                 
        }
</script>
```

thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the code you have until now to jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J5NUp/

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want there to be two identical articles on the webpage by default.

No need for JavaScript! Have the article twice in the page and initially hide one with CSS:

```
article.copy {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, with another CSS rule, show the article on the print page:

```
@media print {
    article.copy {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m7bCT/embedded/result/)

[Mode information on`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) and [a tutorial.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) Unfortunately `@media` doesn't seem to work in IE8 and below.

Comment: does article.copy require copy/pasting of the HTML?

Comment: Depends on how you are generating the content. Either generate it twice or clone the element with JavaScript.